# how to dynamically change masterpage in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to dynamically change masterpage in asp.net mvc application. Like in ASP.Net it can be changed in Page_PreInit Event

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272313/dynamically-changing-master-template-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views expose the `.MasterName` property which specifies which master page to use. You can set this in your controller when returning a view.

For example,

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewResult vr = View();
        vr.MasterName="....";
        return vr;
    }
```

Comment: true - or check out the various overloads of the `View` method, two of them has the ability to specify which master page to render: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller_methods(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: If it's something you want to apply more generally and site wide, this may be way too laborious to have to apply this in each Action for a bunch of Views.

Comment: @Wim good point. It may make more sense to create a common base controller class and adding this code to OnActionExecuted, or overriding/overloading the .View() method

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom `ViewPage` class, and override the `OnPreInit` method and set the `MasterPageFile` property accordingly.

Just change your Views to use your own custom ViewPage class, and you're done.