# Dynamically changing master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

ok so I created this master page file and in its Page_PreInit added the code to change master page at run time after detecing a visitor's country:-

Now, while researching I came across this thread that says "Setting the master page in Page_PreInit event is against the design and spirit of MVC..what is this supposed to mean ???

If not this way, how else am I supposed to change master pages at run time???

Comment: Are you creating an ASP.Net MVC application or a normal ASP.Net app?

Comment: Changed the title. It's obviously a question, and the tags take care of the platform description.

Comment: @Mikael ::using webforms..ok so that applies only to MVC based apps..right ?? so if it WAS MVC based why changing master pages in Page_PreInit event not the right way to go ?

Comment: @Spender :: from now on will choose title keeping that in mind..thanks

Comment: @happysoul. When using MVC you should incorporate the switch of which master page to use in the Controller and not hack it in the View. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272313/dynamically-changing-master-template-in-asp-net-mvc  It's a different way of thinking when creating your app. Some like MVC, some don't. But it has big benefits when it comes to testing and separation of UI and logic and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess what the author of the thread means by the 'Spirit' of MVC. MVC is a tool just like any other in your kit. There are better ways to use tools as well as ways to abuse tools.

I think the answer depends on what is in your master pages. More specifically, what is different between the various countries. If it is largely a matter of layout, logos, colors and other styling, then perhaps this is better handled in your css by injecting a different stylesheet based on the country.

If it is more to do with content and language, then you should probably step back and examine your routing strategy. A common approach is to include country codes in the url. eg: domain.com/UK/product/1 or domain.com/DE/product/1

Another thing to look at is [MVC Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx). Although it is usually used for functionally different parts of a site, I have seen Areas used to partition sites along cultural/country boundaries with some success. This is usually better when there are large functional differences between the different country sites.